# Would a class in Linear Optimization/Programming be useful for a CS degree?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

Would a class in Linear Optimization/Programming be useful for a CS degree?

if it is useful, how useful it is or what is it used for.

Can someone please help me decide.  Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on your interests and focus. Linear Programming appears in many places naturally. However, the standard software packages are pretty good. So you rarely need to implement an algorithm yourself, let alone understand the theory behind it.

Answer (score 0):

It is correct that in CS or when you work as a software engineer you rarely need to implement an optimisation algorithm yourself.

However it is very important to recognise an optimisation problem when you see one in order to be able to apply the correct software packages. This is often not trivial and should be part of every course on optimisation.